# develop own spell checker for other language in MS Word

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, spell-checking

I want to develop spell checker for Sindhi language. I have tried vsto tools but I didn't find any help.

Low level keyboard hooks are also not helpful.

https://github.com/rvknth043/Global-Low-Level-Key-Board-And-Mouse-Hook/blob/master/GlobalLowLevelHooks/KeyboardHook.cs

Is there any help?

Comment: Good luck with your task, unfortunately, SO is not a code writing service, so you have to do it yourself. In case of any problems with actual code, feel free to ask here. Oh, and have you heard about the concept of 'upper case'?

Comment: I must admit i thought there were simple tools to make dictionaries with

Comment: If you just need spelling, Word has a built-in custom dictionary feature. No coding required. File > Options > Proofing.